# MSSQL 2005 query group dates - even dates with no records?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this MS SQL 2005 query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), CreatedOn) as Day,
    COUNT(CreatedOn) as 'Active Cases'
FROM 
    [dbo].[IncidentBase]
WHERE
    (StatusCode != 6 AND StatusCode != 5)
    AND (CaseTypeCode = '200000' OR CaseTypeCode = '200005' OR CaseTypeCode = '200006')
GROUP BY
    DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), CreatedOn)
ORDER BY
    Day DESC
```

And returns something like this:

```
-1   10
-2   6
-5   4
-7   8
```

I would really like it to be like:

```
-1 10
-2 6
-3 0
-4 0
-5 4
-6 0
-7 8
```

(Insert zero between dates with no records)

How can I do that?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an outer join on a subquery returning all the dates

```
SELECT table_cal.day_diff as "Day",
  COALESCE(table_count.base_count,0) as "Active Cases"
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), ibase.CreatedOn) as day_diff 
    FROM [dbo].[IncidentBase] ibase) table_cal
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), ibase.CreatedOn) as day_diff,
    COUNT(ibase.CreatedOn) as base_count
    FROM [dbo].[IncidentBase] ibase
    WHERE ibase.StatusCode NOT IN (5,6) AND ibase.CaseTypeCode IN ('200000','200005','200006')
    GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), ibase.CreatedOn)) table_count
ON (table_cal.day_diff = table_count.day_diff)
ORDER BY table_cal.day_diff DESC
```

The idea behind is quite simple. You need a subquery to generate the list of existing dates, and another to generate the result values. Then you outer join both and replace null values by 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Doesn't quite work though - it just multiplied the "Active Cases" with factor 10. Could you please double check?

Comment: I have updated it now. Since I don't have sample data, I cannot really check

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and I think it's really close now. Please see this: http://gratisupload.dk/billede/thumb/693353/full/

Comment: Can you try to add a DISTINCT in the first subquery ? (I updated my proposal)

Comment: Even more close :) But sometimes it still skips a day and it goes all the way to day 1849+ something even though the last day should be 262. I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: This might come from DATEDIFF(), if getdate() is evaluated on each cycle, value can change.
You can put a limit on the CreatedOn (between) in the first subquery, to be sure not to retrieve too many rows.